# Django rest framework get all related foreign key

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models Organization and Departments. I would like to get all the department related particular organization id by using DRF, how can I do this

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Departments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email= models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    phone=  models.CharField(max_length=30)
    org_linked=models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    user_linked=models.ForeignKey(User)


class OrganizationAndDepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        org_department=facilitesntSerializer(many=True)

        class Meta:
            model = facilites
            fields=('org_department',)


class OrganizationAndDepartmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class =OrganizationAndDepartmentSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full nested representation; declare a nested serializer as follows:

```
class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Departments
        fields = ('__all__')

class OrganizationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    departments = DepartmentsSerializer(many=True, source='org_linked_set', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = (
            'name',
            'description',
            'departments'
        )
```